# AngularJS - Download PDF after trigger generating

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, pdf

I found several articles regarding this topic, but none of them are helping me to that extent that I managed it to download a pdf file with angular.

So the background is, that the user clicks on a button, sends some data to my php script that creates a pdf file. When this is done, the download of the file should start immediately.

The user clicks on this:

```
<button class="btn pull-right" ng-click="printList(products)">Create list</button>
```

Then I have this function:

```
app.controller('Delivery', function($scope, $routeParams, Products, List) {    
$scope.printList = function ($products) {
      List.save({
        'products': $products,
        'selectedDate': $scope.state.dates.start
      }, function () {
      });
    };
});
```

And the factory:

```
app.factory('List', function($resource) {
  return $resource('/backend/FpDashboard/listApi');
});
```

In PHP I have the action which creates the pdf file on the server, but how can I manage my callback from List.save to start the file download?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a same functionality in my project too and this is the code i used to download data as PDF.

```
downloadAsPdf.getfile(data)
      .success(function(data) {
          data.fileName = decodeURIComponent(data.fileName);
          if(isSafariOrIE){
              windowReference.location = data.fileName;
          } else {
              var save = document.createElement('a');
              save.href = data.fileName;
              save.target = '_blank';
              save.download = data.fileName || 'unknown';
              var evt = new MouseEvent('click', {
                  'view': window,
                  'bubbles': true,
                  'cancelable': false
              });
              save.dispatchEvent(evt);
             (window.URL || window.webkitURL).revokeObjectURL(save.href);
       }
   })
```

Comment: Thanks @muhammed-neswine - how do I call this function and what parameter is "data" ?

In my case I will call a function in my callback: function () {
      });

Comment: downloadAsPdf.getfile(data) return just an http promise where I call my API to generate PDF. "data" is just my API params. The code to download is in the success callback.

Comment: @Torben: I hope you got it working. Do upvote it if it helped.